# 2048 resolution street view in google street view api in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-street-view

I wanted to use a high resolution street view in unity raw image.

I asked the service about Premium Plan. And the answer is Google payment is only one payment now and it is not necessary to join the Premium Plan.

But I use the https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview api, the feedback texture max width is always 640, not 2048.(Api key and signature is OK.)

How do I solve the problem to get the high resolution?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you passing a size/scale value to the request? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/dev-guide#Imagesizes

Comment: Yes! I tested the complete http api is 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x2048&location=40.721003, -73.986941&fov=90&heading=0&pitch=0&key=my_API_key&signature=my_signature
And the output texture is 600 x 640.
I don't know whether I use the wrong api?